# Is it possible to call and get result of suspend function from a regular function without using runBlocking

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, camunda

In many youtube videos and even Kotlin documentation, the wording is in such a way that it feels like `runBlocking` should only be used for testing purpose and not in Production code.

But at the same time, I am unable to find a way how I can get the result of a suspend function from a regular function without using `runBlocking`.

Here is the application code where the Camunda BPMN triggers a camunda delegate class (which is a Kotlin class) which inturn calls a suspend function to concurrently call two Api and get the result. The camunda delegate would then put this result in a camunda execution variable.

CamundaInitialDelegate Code:

```
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
class CamundaInitialDelegate(
  private val businessService: BusinessService
) : JavaDelegate {

  override fun execute(execution: DelegateExecution) {
    val result = businessService.businessFunction()
    execution.setVariable("result-of-initial-delegate", result.joinToString())
  }
}
```

BusinessService Code:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class BusinessService {
  fun businessFunction(): List<Int> {
    return runBlocking { //Is there an option other than using runBlocking here???
      // Launch Coroutine
      val result = suspendApiCall() // Call suspending function
      onSuspendingFunctionCompleted(result) // Call non-suspending function with result
    }
  }

  private suspend fun suspendApiCall(): List<Int> {
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
    val async1 = scope.async {
      delay(2000) //mimic an API call
      42
    }
    val async2 = scope.async {
      delay(3000) //mimic another API call
      43
    }
    val listOfDeferred = listOf(async1, async2)
    return listOfDeferred.awaitAll()
  }

  private fun onSuspendingFunctionCompleted(result: List<Int>): List<Int> {
    println("The result is $result")
    return result
  }
}
```

If I use `runBlocking` then the code would work. The reason I made the `suspendApiCall` as a `suspend` function is because then I can make the two api calls in concurrent manner so that it takes around 3 seconds instead of 5 seconds to complete the two Api calls.

(This is for a normal web application and not an Android application)

Comment: Infact, in a typical non-android web application one does not use Kotlin co-routines without using `runBlocking` right?

Comment: I want to use similar code in Production as well because I could not find any alternative to read `suspend` function response in a normal function. Hence the question to see if someone knows another approach. The `callBusinessFunction` will be a real function in Production code and is called from a rest controller for example instead of unit test

Comment: In that case my whole application can only have suspend functions and no normal functions. There will be a valid situation where a normal function should be able to get the result of a suspend function (like when making IO calls like API call)

Comment: Well, your suspend functions can call normal functions, but yeah, as I said, the suspended-ness propagates "up the call chain".  That "rest controller" you mentioned should be a suspending function itself, right? So you can just make `callBusinessFunction` `suspend`.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "valid situation". If you think that blocking is "valid", then feel free to use `runBlocking` :) Not being able to get the result of a suspending function from a non-suspending one is kind of the whole point of "suspending" functions.

Comment: In a typical SpringBoot Kotlin Web application, the code flow is RestController -> Some BusinessService -> calls Database/Api/Soap/etc. Now since the Api call is a `suspend` function so I need to make `BusinessService` class function also as `suspend` and inturn the rest controller function also as `suspend`. So most of the functions in the app would be suspend functions in that case. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't use springboot, so I did a quick google of "springboot kotlin controller suspending" and it gave me [this page](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/spring-boot-kotlin-coroutines). So apparently SpringBoot can take the result in the form of a Mono<T> instead. If you are asking a SpringBoot question, please tag appropriately and [edit] the body to make that clear.

Comment: Also, making all functions as suspend function would be fine in Rest controller. But there could other stuff like I am using `Camunda` which triggers the Kotlin class which inturn calls the BusinessService and Api. So in the Kotlin class I extend `org.camunda.bpm.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate` and override `execute()` method and this method cannot be a `suspend` function due to the error about Conflicting overloads

Comment: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/globalscope-and-runblocking-should-not-be-used-so-how-do-you-start-a-coroutine/24004/3

Comment: It could also be that Kotlin documentation was written thinking about android developers and not the normal/regular web application developers. That is why they made it sound like runBlocking should not be used frequently which is totally not the case when writing code for web applications in Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

This kinda gets at the core of coroutines and why/how they should be used in a real app. And I agree with you that the documentation is lacking to help beginners understand this.

Coroutines are supposed to help solve *concurrency problems*. The usual way this is solved is callbacks. Now is there a way to access the result of a callback before it has executed? No because that would be impossible. Calling a suspend function from a non-suspend function is akin to that!

How do you usually solve that problem when using callbacks? You update something in the calling code *from the callback*. This is actually possible with suspend functions:

```kotlin
suspend fun getMessage(callback: (String) -> Unit) {
  delay(10)
  callback("hello")
}

// In another class (say the fragment). 
fun updateMessage() {
  backgroundScope.launch {
    getMessage {
      mainHandler.post { 
        view.message = it 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Calling updateMessage should update the view. That said **the above code should not be used**. Not because it isn't wrong but because the code just ends up looking like unstructured callback code which defeats the whole purpose of coroutines.

So what's the "right way"? This is highly dependent on the exact situation but a good option in the above case is to use [`StateFlow`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/):

```kotlin
suspend fun getMessage() {
  delay(10)
  return "hello"
}

// In view model
private val message = MutableStateFlow<Message>("")

fun updateMessage() {
  backgroundScope.launch {
    view.message = getMessage()
  }
}
```

Then the `StateFlow` can be *bound* to a view by say using [collectAsStateWithLifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/compose/package-summary#(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow).collectAsStateWithLifecycle(kotlin.Any,androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle,androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle.State,kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext)) if you're using Compose to build your UI (for example).

The exact approach will likely differ from the above if you are building something different (say backend code).

Comment: Nice. My question was about backend code indeed